# Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Failure delivering result runtime exception

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-activity

I am trying to take photo and get image path in my application. I use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to take photo and i get successfully get image path but i also get runtime exception. Here is my code:

Start camera intent:

```
public void openDeviceCam() {

    // Setting parameters to camera intent
    String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

}
```

Get result from camera activity:

```
// Returns after photo taken by phone
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)) {

        DataHandler handler = DataHandler.getInstance();
        // Photo taken
        imageCount++;
        handleUICompanents();

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null,
                null, null);
        int column_index_data = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        // Getting path datas to memory
        Log.v("captured image path", capturedImageFilePath);
        handler.setImagePathsToList(capturedImageFilePath);
        ConnectionHandler connectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler();

        // Calculate passed time during post
        long startSec = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Reques 2
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
        strBuild.append(UrlConstants.swfUrl)
                .append(UrlConstants.swfUrlParamsUploadType)
                .append("image_").append(handler.getSite()).append("_")
                .append(handler.getDomain());
        String respDataToImage = connectionHandler.postImageAsData(
                strBuild.toString(), handler.getImagePath());

        handler.setUpSwfUploadResponseParams(respDataToImage);

        long finishSec = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Request 3
        strBuild = new StringBuilder();
        strBuild.append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrl)
                .append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrlParamsSt)
                .append(handler.getSt()).append("&")
                .append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrlParamsAlbum)
                .append(handler.getPath()).append("&")
                .append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrlParamsUploadedPhotoHash)
                .append(handler.getUploadKey()).append("&")
                .append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrlParamsCdnDomain)
                .append(UrlConstants.cdnDomain).append("&")
                .append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrlParamsAppId)
                .append(handler.getSite()).append("&")
                .append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrlParamsNetmeraDomain)
                .append(handler.getDomain()).append("&")
                .append(UrlConstants.savePhotoUrlParamsViewerId)
                .append(handler.getOpensocialViewerId()).append("&");

        connectionHandler.getData(strBuild.toString(), null);

        Log.v("passed time", String.valueOf(finishSec - startSec));
        Log.v("upload path", handler.getPath());

        // Delete temp image path
        // deleteTempImages();

    }
}
```

And here is my logcat error output:

```
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.inomera.ttmobilerehber/com.inomera.ttmobilerehber.TTMobileRehberActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:116)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at com.inomera.ttmobilerehber.TTMobileRehberActivity.onActivityResult(TTMobileRehberActivity.java:155)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
11-12 14:43:10.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20850):     ... 11 more
11-12 14:43:10.489: ERROR/(162): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248327/my-android-camera-uri-is-returning-a-null-value-but-the-samsung-fix-is-in-place

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NullPointerException` on line 155 of `TTMobileRehberActivity`, in one of your calls to `Log.v()`. Unfortunately, you declined to point out which line this is.

Since you say:

> i get successfully get image path

then I have to assume the failing call is not:

```
Log.v("captured image path", capturedImageFilePath);
```

The only other `Log.v()` call that could fail is:

```
Log.v("upload path", handler.getPath());
```

and that is referring to some `DataHandler` class, presumably of your own creation.

Comment: yes it was a problem too and i solved it but i still have an error. My error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=null} still is the same

Comment: @cagryInside: Scroll down, find the "Caused by:" line, and diagnose your problem.