# Camera capture activity MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE doesn't write to Uri

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

This is weird. The following code was working a few weeks ago, and now it is not:

```
private void onClick()
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   mOriginalUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"original" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
   Log.d("path", mOriginalUri.getPath());
   intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOriginalUri);
   intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
   startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
   switch( requestCode )
   {
   case CAMERA_REQUEST:
       if(resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK)
          Log.d("path", mOriginalUri.getPath());
       break;
   }
}
```

Somehow the camera capture activity is losing track of my Uri and setting it to null. I get a NPE when printing the path in the onActivityResult. How can I resolve this? I'm using Android 4.1.2 API 16 on a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: I get a Null Pointer Exception in the onActivityResult when I try to print the path.

Comment: Also check that the image which you are trying to get is exists at that path or not ?

Comment: Have you tried or not? Is your issue resolved or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue of the camera sometimes returning the image and sometimes returning null. I had the same setup of writing the image to a file.

I kicked off the camera intent from onCreate(), not an onClick() method.

When I locked the screen orientation of the intent (to portrait, but that does not matter), the problem went away. May want to try that and report back if that made a difference.

This may also be relevant:
[Camera activity causing uri to go to null when screen orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214350/camera-activity-causing-uri-to-go-to-null-when-screen-orientation-changes/15892730#15892730)