# Main Activity overwritten when control returns from Camera subactivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-camera

```
private File getOutputPhotoFile() {
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getPackageName());
    if (!directory.exists()) 
    {
        if (!directory.mkdirs()) 
        {
            responsetxt.setText("Failed to create directory");
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
            return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.UK).format(new Date());
    //responsetxt.setText(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"  + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    return new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"  + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

public void cam_get_photo()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputPhotoFile());
    responsetxt.setText(fileUri.toString());
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ );         
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ) 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            Uri photoUri;
            if(data == null)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "data null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                photoUri = fileUri;
                if( photoUri == null) Toast.makeText(this, "data null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                {
                    File myfile = new File(photoUri.toString());
                    responsetxt.setText(photoUri.toString());
                }
                //String outpath = myfile.getAbsolutePath();
                //Toast.makeText(this, outpath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                if(photo != null)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully in: \n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ImageView photoImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_image);
                photoImage1.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        } 
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Callout for image capture failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, in `cam_get_photo()` method, I am calling `startActivityforResult()`, also I am storing **fileUri** as global variable before calling `startActivityforResult()`. When the execution returns to the **MainActivity** from the **CameraActivity**, I am observing that the original **MainActivity** is lost and new **MainActivity** is created because of which the value of **fileUri** is becoming null. So when I check the value of fileUri in `onActivityResult()` function I am finding it null.

This is a peculiar problem because I need to access `fileUri` which was stored before as global in the original Main Activity. But the `MainActivity` gets overwritten when the control returns from the Camera sub-activity and `fileUri` is lost.

Please suggest some workarounds or ways to overcome this problem. Please let me know in case of any clarifications required.

Comment: PS :- I also observe that after the Camera Activity returns there is a screen rotation in my phone. I suspect that due to screen rotation a new Main activity is getting created and the original Main Activity is lost. but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem in an answer in this link [Camera activity causing uri to go to null when screen orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214350/camera-activity-causing-uri-to-go-to-null-when-screen-orientation-changes?rq=1) .Its resolved by locking screen orientation in manifest.

Locking the screen orientation of the invoking Activity fixed the issue for me. If you don't want to lock yours, you can create an Activity with locked orientation just for calling the camera, then returning the result to your 'real' activity.

To lock the screen orientation, put this into the activity definition in your manifest (both lines):

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

"portrait" can also be "landscape"